# Command Prompt to Text File with no OverWrite?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt

I need to send some information from the command prompt to a text file but I would like to have it just continue adding to the text file.

For example

```
ipconfig >C:\Users\Desktop\File.TXT
```

and then

```
tasklist >C:\Users\Dekstop\File.TXT.
```

When the second command runs it overwrites the file. I would like it to just add on to the file.

Comment: IIRC, >> instead of > will do this.  BTW, I'm editing this to add the Windows tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
tasklist >> C:\Users\Desktop\File.TXT
```

for the second command

Comment: Thats the one, double pipe. Ahh the memories.

Comment: They're poor memories.  That's not a pipe.  (-:

Answer (score 0):

`>>` is used to append the changes to the old file:

```
 ipconfig > C:\Users\Desktop\File.TXT

 tasklist >> C:\Users\Dekstop\File.TXT
```